# Calculate the Reverse of a recursion function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

I have a recursion function as follows:

$$R(0) = 1$$

$$R(1) = 1$$

$$R(2) = 2$$

$$R(2n) = R(n) + R(n + 1) + n ,\qquad \forall n \gt 1$$

$$R(2n + 1) = R(n - 1) + R(n) + 1 ,\quad \forall n\ge 1$$

Now I want to find the reverse of this function. I know that first of all, I should solve the relation then after finding the function calculate the reverse. But the problem is that since the relations are different for even and odd numbers I cant figure out how to find a unique solution or even when I try to solve them separately, since the variables have coefficient it seems complicated.

For more clarification, here is an example, of how you can find the inverse of the Tower of Hanoi:

$$H_n = 2H_{n−1} + 1$$
$$= 2(2H_{n−2} + 1) + 1 = 2^2 H_{n−2} + 2 + 1$$
$$= 2^2 (2H_{n−3} + 1) + 2 + 1 = 2^3 H_{n−3} + 2^2 + 2 + 1$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$= 2^{n−1} H_1 + 2^{n−2} + 2^{n−3} + · · · + 2 + 1$$
$$= 2^{n−1} + 2^{n−2} + · · · + 2 + 1$$
$$= 2^{n} − 1.$$

Now the inverse is

$$\log_2(F - 1)$$

Comment: Is your formula correct? may be 'for even $n$' and 'for odd $n$' instead of 'for $n>1$' and 'for $n\geq 1$, resp.

Comment: $2n$ is already even and $2n+1$ is already odd. Formulae seem correct to me.

Comment: It's unclear for me what you call "compute the inverse". Could you give an example ?

Comment: @HasanHeydari Yes they are correct.

Comment: For there to be an inverse, the function has to be bijective. Is it?

Comment: I added an example

Comment: @IvanNeretin I'm not sure. I need to find the function first

Comment: Thanks for the example: what you call an **inverse** is plainly an **explicit expression** as opposed to the implicit form given by the recurrence definition.

Comment: @JeanMarie You mean it's fundamentally impossible or just for this particular example?

Comment: No, I don't mean that at all.  It was just a vocabulary remark. I suggest to say that you look for a **closed form formula** for the general term of your recurrence that allows you to compute $R_n$ without creeping through other values $R_k$...

Comment: Thanks, I see. Can you please give me some clues on this? I mean if I want to gain a functionality as the inverse function from this recursion relation, is it really necessary to calculate the inverse? or can I use other approaches?